# How to apply scale and rotation to image in Offscreen rendering on React Native Skia?

Tags: react-native

Using this example from:
https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/discussions/1359#discussioncomment-4983561

```
const offscreen = Skia.Surface.MakeOffscreen(ctx.width, ctx.height);
const canvas = offscreen.getCanvas();
canvas.drawImage(....) // draw your image

// Draw
offscreen.flush();
// Get the image
offscreen.makeImageSnapshot()
```

`drawImage()` only accepts: image, left, top, paint params.
Is there a way to apply scale and rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Not sure if this is the recommended/right way but it works based on what I need.

```
canvas.save(); // If I correctly understand, this creates new stack. No documentation though (as of 3/13/23). I went through the codes to know more about it.
canvas.concat(skMatrix); // since I have the matrix (which has the x, y, skewX, skewY, scaleX, scaleY) data I pass the value here
canvas.drawImage(skImage, 0, 0);
canvas.restore();
```